# In argument type '[ItemA]', 'ItemA' does not conform to expected type 'Sortable'

Tags: swift, generics

I have run into a weird error using Swift, but I can't seem to find the issue. The error should not be thrown I think, and I have verified this issue with the code below in a playground.

```
protocol Sortable {
}

protocol ItemA: Sortable {
}

func sortItems<T: Sortable>(items: [T]) -> [T] {
    // do the sorting here
    return items
}

let list: [ItemA] = []

sortItems(items: list)
```

Comment: A protocol cannot conform to itself. A generic type constrained to a protocol like `T: Sortable` **must** be a concrete type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass another protocol that inherits from the constrained protocol in current Swift version (4.1).

If you make `ItemA` a `struct`, a `class` or an `enum`, it will work.

**OR**

If you would change your `sortItems` implementation to simply take `Sortable` as an argument like this, then you can use another protocol that inherits from `Sortable`, but you will lose the information about the type.

```
func sortItems(items: [Sortable]) -> [Sortable] {
    // do the sorting here
    return items
}
```

You can find more information on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself/43408193#43408193).

Comment: But the objects inheriting from ItemA are structs, so if I want to fix this, I will have to change all the inheriting objects to `class`, as `struct` cannot inherit from another `struct` or `class`?

Comment: Maybe you would show more of the members (protocol, structs, classes, enums) that implement those protocols and what is the goal.

Comment: Also, is this a bug or a feature? Read: will this be solved in a future Swift version?

Comment: Is there a reason why the `list` variable is not simply the array of those structs that conform to `ItemA`?

Comment: @vrwim is is not a bug and I am not aware of any changes to this in near future

Comment: There are different `struct`s (data objects to interchange through `Codable` with the API, hence structs) that inherit from `ItemA`, and `Sortable`, I want to pass the list (that I have as `ItemA` in this viewcontroller, as this viewcontroller shows multiple objects conforming to this protocol) to the sort method. This feels like a bug though, is there a link you can give me where I can read more about this specific issue of not being able to pass another protocol that inherits from the constrained protocol?

Comment: Unfortunately I not aware of any resources where you could read more about this.

Comment: I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself/43408193#43408193) They explain it pretty well there, also they suggest using `@objc` to avoid the errors, but in my case (with `struct`s, that's not gonna be possible). I'm going to make ItemA a class and change all inheriting objects to `class`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Depending on your case, you can always try to use composition first, before jumping to inheritance.